# PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**Gem file:**

```
gem "oauth2"
gem "omniauth-gmail"
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
```

I am new in ruby on rails . I am succeffuly sign up with facebook  but when I will try to sign up with gmail  then I got the following PG error.

pls give me any suggestion , I also change the data type of address from string to text but did not get result.

> ---
>
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /users PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR:  value too long for type
>   character varying(255) : INSERT INTO "users" ("address", "city",
>   "confirmation_sent_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at",
>   "country", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip",
>   "email", "encrypted_password", "facebookimage", "image",
>   "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "latitude", "longitude",
>   "membership", "provider", "remember_created_at",
>   "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count",
>   "state", "uid", "unconfirmed_email", "updated_at", "username", "zip")
>   VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14,
>   $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28,
>   $29) RETURNING "id" Application Frames All Frames rescue in log
>   activerecord (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb, line 285
>
> ---

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920028/pgstringdatarighttruncation-error-postgresql-string255-limit-heroku

Answer (score 4):

The field should be of type `:text`, not of `:string` in your migration file.

Comment: Which field? Is it possible to tell?

Answer (score 0):

Or, here is direct method using the pg:psql from the heroku command line. You should definitely add a migration file that addresses this as well to not create any discrepancies.

http://www.dchapman.io/posts/changing-column-type-in-postgresql-rails

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a outdated  migration test db in remote servers.

Try:

```
rake db:migrate db:test:prepare
```

and run your migration again.