# RoR Postgresql on Heroku error: PG::StringDataRightTruncation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a ruby on rails project that allows me to submit a comment (called a note). It seems to work fine on my computer and I'm using sql or whatever comes stock with rails.

After I put the app on heroku everything is working good except now my notes that are longer that 255 characters return an error.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the database since on localhost:3000 I can save hundreds of lines of text.

I however don't know anything about databases - can someone point me in the right direction with this error? the error is:

> PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR: value too long for type
>   character varying(255)

Here's the migration for notes, and its defined as a string, not a Character:

```
class CreateNotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :notes do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :comment
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :record_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: I just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920028/pgstringdatarighttruncation-error-postgresql-string255-limit-heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using :text field type for attributes that will hold more than 255 characters.

```
class CreateNotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :notes do |t|
    t.text :title
    t.text :comment
    t.integer :user_id
    t.integer :record_id

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

This will only work if you are able to recreate your database by doing

```
rake db:drop 
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

If you are not in the position to reset the database you will have to do a new migration with

```
def change
  change_column :notes, :title, :text   
  change_column :notes, :comment, :text   
end
```

Comment: I've made the change but I don't know how to push the change to heroku without destroying all the data in the database. "heroku run rake db:migrate --app [appname]" did help

Comment: updated my answer to reflect updating a production db without destroying the data.. make sure you are creating a NEW migration